# Redirect to separate URL if 403 or 404

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have an Nginx setup whereby I included a file with whitelisted IPs that can access my site's admin portal `admin.site.com`. It usually returns a 403 forbidden or 404 depending on the configuration if an unauthorized IP attempts to access my admin portal, but I feel this is not very nice.
I need to redirect all users to `site.com` if the response is 403 or 404. Here is what I have

```
server {
    # listen on port 80 (http)
    listen 80;
    server_name admin.site.com;

    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        allow all;
        root /var/www/.well-known/acme-challenge/;
        default_type "text/plain";
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location / {
        # redirect any requests to the same URL but on https
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    # listen on port 443 (https)
    listen 443 http2 ssl;
    server_name admin.site.com;

    root /var/www/admin.site.com/site-frontend/;
    index index.html;
        location / {
       include /etc/nginx/snippets/whitelist.conf;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    # location of SSL certificate
    ssl_certificate /etc/some/path/admin.site.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/some/path/admin.site.com/privkey.pem;
    ...
    ...
    ... 

    # write access and error logs to /var/log
    access_log /var/log/nginx/admin.site.com_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/admin.site.com_error.log;
}
```

This is the bit responsible for checking if an IP is in the whitelist:

```
    index index.html;
        location / {
       include /etc/nginx/snippets/whitelist.conf;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
```

How do I redirect to `site.com` if a 403 is returned?

Comment: You should simply return 301 or 302 instead of 403 and it will work out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `error_page` directive to redirect the 403 and/or 404 status pages to an external site. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) for details.

For example:

```
error_page 404 403 =301 https://example.com/;
```